# Monetizing Azure Functions securely on the Azure Marketplace

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions

This question is regarding protecting the IP,  and hiding the code inside my Azure Function that I plan to deploy on the Azure Marketplace under PAYG model.

The Function:

- C# code, spread across about a dozen class files, compiled as a DLL
- Is triggered by a BlobTrigger.
- Deployed through an ARM template using zipDeploy.

The ARM Template:

- Requires customer to enter the connection string for the Blob, and URL/credentials for a REST API.
- Requires the customer to choose the hosting plan for the function app (Premium Plan -EP1/EP2/EP3 )
- Deploys the required resources (storage, insights, app-service-plan, function).
- Uses zipDeploy to deploy the DLLs
- Starts the function

The Issue:

- Once deployed, the client can download the function assets (as a zip
  file).
- The zip file can be hosted as a new function (with a different configuration).
- This new function will not be tracked by the Marketplace (revenue loss for the publisher).

Can anyone please suggest any solution to this? Any other workflow, deployment model, etc.

One possible solution is to embed the resourceID of the VM in the source-code, compile it to get the DLL, obfuscate the DLL (to avoid decompiling code and replacing the resourceID), create the zip, and use this zip for zipDeploy. But I can't find any way to automate this, and plug this into the ARM template.

Comment: can't you offer as SaaS? (some endpoint + api key and that's it)

Comment: thanks.I didn't think of that option, but yes, it will work. Will implement it if no other solution exists.